# Modify only one field of the interface with the useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, interface

I defined this interface and hook with an initialization:

```
 interface userInterface {
  email:string
  name:string
  last_name:string
 }

 const [userData, setUserData] = useState <userInterface> ({
  email:"",
  name:"",
  last_name:"",
  
 })
```

then if you just wanted to change the name only. How should it be done with setUserData?

That is, I want to leave the email and the last_name as they are but only modify the name

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the issue you encountered with that/those attempt(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jay Lu is correct.

I wanted to note a couple things.

#### Typescript Interfaces

- Interface name should use PascalCasing
- Key names should use camelCasing
- Prefer utility types where appropriate
- `[optional]` Interface name should be prefaced with a capital "I"

  - This used to be a convention now more people are moving away from it. Your choice

**Interface Update: 1) Naming Conventions**

```
interface UserInterface {
  email:string
  name:string
  lastName:string
}
```

The next thing we want to do is use a utility type to simplify the verbosity of our code.

**Interface Update: 2) Utility Type**
We will actually change this interface to a type to easily use the utility type `Record`.

```
type UserInterface = Record<"email" | "name" | "lastName", string>;
```

As for your component, you didn't provide much detail there so I will provide details on setting state.

#### Functional Component: Updating State

It's very important to establish what variables or data you need to "subscribe" to changes. For instance, if the email and name are static (never changing) there is no need to have them in state which would result in a state variable defaulting to an empty string:

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");
```

If that's not the case and you indeed need to update and manage the email, name, and lastName updating state is simple: spread the existing state with the updated value. You do this using the setter function provided in the tuple returned from useState. In this case that's `setUserData`. The setter function takes a value that is the same type as your default **or** it can accept a callback function where it provides you the **current** state value. This is really powerful and really useful for updating a state object variable. In your case we have:

```js
setUserData((previous) => ({...previous, name: "Updated name value"});
```

What's happening here? The `setUserData` provides us the "previous" state if we pass it a callback. On the first call of this function "previous" is:

```js
{
  email: "",
  name: "",
  lastName: ""
}
```

We are taking that value and spreading it over in a **new** object with the updated value. This is the same as Object.assign. If you spread a key that already exists in the object it will be replaced. After we spread our state object looks like:

```js
{
  email: "", // didn't change because we didn't pass a new value
  lastName: "", // didn't change because we didn't pass a new value
  name: "Updated name value" // changed because we passed a new value
}
```

Which means, if you wanted to update the email you can by simply doing:

```js
setUserData((previous) => ({...previous, email: "hello@world.com"});
```

Now your state object will be:

```js
{
  email: "hello@world.com",
  lastName: "",
  name: "Updated name value"
}
```

And if you call `setUserData` with a callback again, the previous value with be that object above.

If you want to set it back to the original values you can update the entire state without using the callback. Why? Because we don't need to preserve any values since we want to overwrite it:

```js
setUserData({ email: "", lastName: "", name: ""});
```

There is a slight improvement to that though. If we decide that at some point we want to "reset to default" we should store the default value in a variable and reuse it. Not 100% necessary but it might be a good update especially if you have a complex component.

**Quick Note on the Power of Typescript**
If you were to try and update state with a new key that you didn't have defined before let's say "helloWorld" typescript will give you an error because "helloWorld" is not defined in your UserData type.

Hopefully @Jay Lu's answer and some of this info helped. If you provide more details we might be able to offer more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple expample:

```js
setUserData((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: 'Name you want' }));
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const DemoComponent = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    email: "",
    name: "",
    last_name: ""
  });

  const handleBtnOnClick = (name) => {
    setUserData((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: name }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleBtnOnClick("Jay");
        }}
      >
        Jay
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleBtnOnClick("Andy");
        }}
      >
        Andy
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleBtnOnClick("Olivia");
        }}
      >
        Olivia
      </button>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(userData, null, "\t")}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <DemoComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```